# image should always have 100% height but with aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I have an image in a website (the website is responsive). the image should always have 100% height of the parent div (that has a height of 100%) but with aspect ratio.
[my example](http://herrfischerhamburg.de/stackoverflow/)

I tried with CSS:

```
max-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
width: auto!important;
```

But this way the picture has always 100% height of it's original size. I want it bigger than it's original size, but with aspect ratio.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you considered changing your CSS to the following?

```
img{width:100%; height:auto;}
```

That way all of your images will respond to the width of their parent element and keep their aspect ratio

Comment: this way it's not responsive in height.

Comment: i think there is no CSS only solution for this. someone made this: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/y2L3Q/ and it fits very good. i have to figure out how to paste this in my responsive design.

Comment: i used this solution now because every other options lead to more problems.

Answer (score 1):

Change the CSS to:

```
height: 100%;
display: block;
float: right;
```

By removing all width references, most if not all browsers will scale it proportionally and keep the aspect ratio. By specifying the height as 100%, it will fit the height of the image to the height of the parent container and stay responsive.

Comment: okay, but it is not responsive. as you see in my demo the site is responsive and when i shrink the window in it's width the image won't shrink it's width your method.

Comment: this is exactly what i need: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/y2L3Q/
only proble is: when it goes to responsive and i give the parent DIV a height of "auto" it acts crazy.

Answer (score -1):

Use the CSS tags "width" and "height" to make it bigger. For example:

```
width: 200%;
height: 200%;
```

Good luck!

[*Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yTyH8/)